# How to locate a prompt message of type in-context using selenium and Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, prompt, qwebelement

Please refer the below screenshot for the same :

[image: example]

Comment: Please tell us what have you already tried, and where did you get lost?

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to figure out how to do this is to open the Selenium IDE in Firefox, record a test in which you type some random text in the box, and then export the test case as Java code. That'll give you an example to work off of.